# How to keep a button to the right of a datagrid header

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to add a button to the datagrid header column and keep it at the right-most edge of the header column... no matter how wide it is. In my Xaml code I am using a **DataTemplate** where I attach the header column title and add a toggle button with a popup window.

```
<DataGrid>
 <DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <DataGrid.Resources>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

            <!--TODO: THIS IS THE BUTTON I WANT TO ANCHOR TO THE RIGHT-->
            <ToggleButton Name="FilterButton" Grid.Column="1" Content="▼" Margin="2, 1, 1, 1" Padding="1, 0"/>
           <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=FilterButton, Path=IsChecked}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=FilterButton}" StaysOpen="False">
            <Border Background="White" Padding="3">
              <TextBox Width="300"/>
            </Border>
           </Popup>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

When I launch my application I do see the header column with the toggle button right next to it. But I need it to be in the rightmost of any column header. Like this:

[image]

Can someone help me understand how to go about doing this with the code I currently have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of fiddling, here's what I did to get it to work:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
            <Grid Margin="0, 0, -5, 0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                <!--TODO: THIS IS THE BUTTON I WANT TO ANCHOR TO THE RIGHT-->
                <ToggleButton Name="FilterButton" Grid.Column="1" Content="▼" Margin="2, 1, 1, 1" Padding="1, 0"/>
                <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=FilterButton, Path=IsChecked}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=FilterButton}" StaysOpen="False">
                    <Border Background="White" Padding="3">
                        <TextBox Width="300"/>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}" Header="Test"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

There are two key changes.

First, I added this to `DataGrid.Resources`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
```

Which lets the `HeaderTemplate` fill the the entire header.

Second, I added a negative right margin to the `Grid`:

```
<Grid Margin="0, 0, -5, 0">
```

This compensates for the internal padding of the header's control template, moving the button fully to the right.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know how I can make my textBox control appear to the Left of the ToggleButton? Right now it appears Right of the ToggleButton and covers the other column headers.

Comment: Give a name to the above `ContentControl` and set the `PlacementTarget` to that instead of `FilterButton`

Comment: Or, if you need evern more control, you can use `Popup.Placement="Relative"` and set `HorizontalOffset` and `VerticalOffset`.

Comment: @KeithStein  and AJITH Thank you guys, I got it working with your added input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the content inside the header is Autosized. What you need to do is to change the Horizontal Alignment of the content. You can define a style for Column header and that will resolve the issue.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style  TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```